# Executing StoredProcedure takes incredible amount of time in EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework-6

I am running EF6 (v6.2.0) in ASP.NET MVC5.

When executing a certain StoredProcedure via EF6's SqlQuery() function I have to wait for about 2 minutes(!) to get the result in memory.

The StoredProcedure takes about 9 - 12 seconds in the database due to some complex calculations and is called with 11 parameters:

```
exec sp_Calculation @q, @y, @gn, @gesa, @rg, @cl, @yc, @vlv, @vlb, @ugv, @ugb
```

The result is about **2.1 MB** of data (*~9000 rows, 49 columns*).

Total execution time: `00:00:11.711`

In code I call it like this:

```
dbContext.Database.Log = s => Trace.Write(s);
return await dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<CalculationResult>("exec sp_Calculation @q, @y, @gn, @gesa, @rg, @cl, @yc, @vlv, @vlb, @ugv, @ugb", parameters).ToListAsync(token);
```

Trace:

```
exec sp_Calculation @q, @y, @gn, @gesa, @rg, @cl, @yc, @vlv, @vlb, @ugv, @ugb

-- @q: 'null' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- @y: '1101' (Type = Int16, IsNullable = false)
-- @gn: 'null' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- @gesa: '1' (Type = Byte, IsNullable = false)
-- @rg: 'null' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- @cl: '4' (Type = Byte, IsNullable = false)
-- @yc: '17' (Type = Int16, IsNullable = false)
-- @vlv: 'null' (Type = Int16, IsNullable = false)
-- @vlb: 'null' (Type = Int16, IsNullable = false)
-- @ugv: 'null' (Type = Int16, IsNullable = false)
-- @ugb: 'null' (Type = Int16, IsNullable = false)
-- Executing asynchronously at 19.07.2018 18:27:23 +02:00
-- Completed in 114479 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

My first guess was the network as a bottleneck, but calling the StoredProc on the Webserver via SSMS is also very fast. So network should not be the problem.

Here is the Call Stack from dotTrace with the big bottleneck:
[image]
What is weird is the extremely long execution times of the native assemblies.

Can someone clarify what exactly is going on there and how to resolve the issue?

**EDIT:**
I just found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993309/what-is-snireadsyncoverasync-and-why-would-it-take-a-long-time-to-complete) with a similar problem and will try to find out some more about it. Maybe it **is** the network.

**EDIT 2:**
I do need all the data in memory due to some preprocessing before creating a csv file from it. The bottleneck seems to be in the `SNINativeMethodWrapper`. I do not need help to perform my task with other libraries. I just want to get the data faster in memory.

Comment: ORMs aren't meant for *reporting queries*. Waiting for 9K rows to return, convert them into a list and *then* use them is slow too, and probably results in a lot of reallocations. Use the IEnumerable to start processing results as they come. After all, for reporting or exporting you don't need all the data, you can start writing the results out as soon as the first row arrives.

Comment: You could also use a microORM like Dapper. Since you don't deal with entities, you don't need change tracking, update support and all the other features a full ORM provides. Just mapping of the DbDataReader rows to CalculationResult objects

Comment: We use EF6 all over the application and use pretty much all its features. So swapping out is not an option right now. The thing is, there will be some more processing after loading the data. But loading alone takes that long.

Does EF6 take the object allocation into account when showing the time spent in the Trace?

Comment: that's no reason to use the *wrong* features. SO uses EF too. And Dapper. I think ADO.NET too where it's necessary. ORMs are *still* not suitable for reporting an export queries

Comment: plain ADO.NET gives me the same results, so it's not a problem with EF6 per se.
Some native stuff seems to go crazy, but I need to know what exactly is going wrong there.

Comment: then it's the stored procedure itself. You haven't provided any relevant information though so it's impossible to help. Relevant information is the code itself, the execution plan, the table schemas and the indexes. Use SQL Server's Activity Monitor to see what's actually going on, whether there's any locking, blocking involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was heavy load between the database and linked servers.
The native API had a hard time to push the whole record set through the SQL Network Interface. So there is no problem with the code itself.

Everything works as fast as expected when load between linked servers was low.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and offcourse SSMS will execute faster.

The problem is that all records are assigned to the respective POCO and its properties it iterates through every value until it produces a huge set of object.

**What i did to address the issue :**

I created a pagination in the sproc (sql level paging).
No one can view 9000+ records at a time unless you are a CYBORG.
So just get 10-100 records from the result set when the store procedure is executed.

**Updated :**

If you need to retrieve result set for creating an excel, i would suggest the possible ways to do so :

- Create excel file directly from the [sql](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926), taking the result set
  from db to C# is time consuming.
- If you still need it in server side
  then i would suggest you use [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started) or any other well maintained
  third party libraries to generate excel for you at *server side* (EPPlus is what i use
  and it does not take longer than 5 secs for me excluding SP execution
  time)
- Switching back to ado.net for report generation is viable, due to [performance](https://exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/) difference between EF and ADO
- Optimize your query, refine it.
- If your hands are still tied up by the client, then bear with the loading time you are currently experiencing ;)

Comment: So the allocation might be the bottleneck. Is that what you mean?
I know no one can view them, but our customer needs them all at once. Paging would mean I would have to run the calculations again and again for each page. which takes 9-12 sec each. The Stored Proc cannot be changed unfortunately

Comment: @cmxl yes. Paging usually adds 1-2 s maximum, in my case i barely noticed the time difference. Secondly, try to persuade your clientele into pagination -unless client is using the result set to generate an excel report.

Comment: it is actually excel :'(

Comment: thank you for your suggestions! I added my question with a link to a very similar problem that I can see in the dotTrace result. I just tried it with plain old ADO.NET and it was as slow as EF6 unfortunately.

Comment: @cmxl that means that the *stored procedure* is slow and transfers too much. As for Excel, EPPlus can generate an Excel sheet from a DbDataReader with `sheet.FromDataReader()`. You shouldn't have to read everything before starting to create the sheet.

Comment: @cmxl unfortunately EF is built on top of ADO, so if it is making no difference then you need to revisit your sp.

Comment: Also be careful with paging because order by together with top or using FETCH FIRST and OFFSET (which also uses order by) works as filter. If your order by is not absolute you may loose rows under certain conditions. For example, at a 30 rows per page setup, row #31 will not be displayed at page (correct) but if this row get position #30 (may happen without data modifications if order by is not absolute) on the next query execution getting page #2 it will not be displayed on page #2 either.